# What is output of this query and Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
declare @table as table
(
  id int identity(1,1), salary int 
)

insert into @table values(1000)
insert into @table values(2000)
insert into @table values(5000)
insert into @table values(4000)
insert into @table values(1000)
insert into @table values(8000)
insert into @table values(9000)
insert into @table values(6000)
insert into @table values(1000)
insert into @table values(7000)
insert into @table values(3000)

select 
    A.salary 
from 
    @table as A
where 
    (select count(*) 
     from @table B
     where b.salary < A.salary) > 5
```

Comment: Why don't you just **run it yourself** and see?

Comment: but why this result comming i m not understand result of query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will display the salary which is greater than 5000

[image]

Comment: Venkatesh Rangu:why?

Comment: @AnkitBhanderi because 5000 have more than 5 records less than it self.

3 - 1000
1 - 2000
1 - 3000
1 - 4000 
total count is 6   ( 6  > 5)

if 5000 has more than 5 records 
others which are bigger than 5000  will have more than 5

Comment: here you are  checking with number 5
where b.salary < A.salary)>5  means  suppose i put the number 1 means it will display count of salary b and that is greater than salary a then displaying the result
it mainly depend upon the number mentioned in the where condition

Comment: The query will read from A sequentially then counting values from B against the 1 row from A.

Comment: You can see output and execution plan on sqlfiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

In the query, you are self joining a table.

And You are counting number of records from inner table which are higher than current record of outer table.

So it will give you 5 records from `table A` which are higher than 5 records from inner query

Sub Query `select count(*) from @table B where b.salary < A.salary` will give you number of records which are less in salary than of `table A`

And So the result.

Answer (score 0):

your query gonna return

```
   5000
   8000
   9000
   6000
   7000
```

because as per your query it will check if a record is **greater then 6** other records of the table or not.
as the inner query counting it for you.

if you remove all entries of 1000 the result will change to

```
  8000
  9000
```

because now only these two records are greater then 6 other records of the tables.